# Path of bundle file when run ng serve in angular cli

Tags: angular

When I run ng serve I have open port localhost:4200 with js file loaded path like:

`http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js`

how can I change path to

`http://localhost:4200/anypath/polyfills.bundle.js`

Comment: you are actually running your app, just navigate to the http://localhost:4200 or use ng-serve -o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular Cli do not support this case, so my solution is  using ng build in watch mode and config outDir in .angular-cli.json. Thank for your help

Answer (score 2):

This is possible if you run with the **ng serve** parameter `--baseHref=/anypath`

If you run using **npm start** then edit the package.json file to add `--baseHref=/anypath` to the ng serve command.

You will also need to either change the `<base href="/anypath" />` inside the index.html file or remove that base from the index file and instead provide an `APP_BASE_HREF` provider in your app.module.ts - an example below:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
...
...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
    ...
  ],
  ...
  ...
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
      useValue: '/anypath,
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This works for me. I needed to debug locally simulating as though the angular site was deployed to a sub folder on the website, not the root.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to load this path? Ng serve should just start your app normally on /

Comment: i want create multi app in one project, so, i need multipart of js file for each single app

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I get your question correctly, but I had similar issue to use image files.

I used the "Assets" folder and everything worked fine.

UPDATE: improving answer.

If you put "polyfills.bundle.js" inside /src/assets you will be able to locate if at the following address

```
http://localhost:4200/assets/polyfills.bundle.js
```

I hope that helps you out.